# Javascript wait for function response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code:

```
myFunc();
bar();
```

myFunc() is making an ajax request

I don't want to execute bar() until myFunc()'s request has completed.

I also do not want to move the call to bar() inside of myFunc.

possible?

*EDIT*

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
var FOO = {
 init: function(blah)
 {
  // Callbacks to pass to the AJAX challenge data load
  var callbacks = {
   myFunc1: function(){ myFunc1(blah); },
   myFunc2: function(){ myFunc2(blah); },
  };

  this.bar(callbacks); // Load the challenge data and setup the game
 },
 bar: function(callbacks) { ..loop through and execute them.. }

};
```

Comment: Jan and Jerome both have valid answers, personally I'm leaning towards Jeromes since thats the typical way to do stuff in JavaScript

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? There's no justifiable reason to deal with all the cross-browser quirks instead of using a premade Ajax library that supports callbacks.

Comment: I wasn't trying to reinvent the wheel.  I just didn't know what I was doing, period.

Jerome's suggestion worked out great.

See the *EDIT* for what I ended up with:

I think that's ideal...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to do what you are looking for, you must find a way for *bar()* to communicate with *myFunc()*.

When you say that you do not want to move the call to *bar()* inside *myFunc()* this can be interpreted in several ways.

For example, you could make *bar()* a parameter of *myFunc()*

```
function bar() {
   // do what bar() does
}

function myFunc(callback) {
   // use callback in the onreadystatechange property of the xmlhtprequest object
}

myFunc(bar)
```

I hope this will help you

Jerome Wagner

Answer (score 1):

IF you can add a kind of a flag that will indicate that myFunc() has finished with its request you can do it, but this is not a good idea - best practice is to use callbacks.

Try this code:

```
var successRequest = false;
myFunc(); // when get the response set successRequest to true

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (successRequest) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        bar();
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Does setInterval works as global? I mean if I set interval at some function and if I reset it another(or at same function with a new rewuest) does it understands other setIntervals or not?

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible unless you use a synchronous request which is no longer AJAX and something I wouldn't recommend you doing as it will freeze the UI until the request completes and users hate having their browser freezing.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

You could achieve it with the side effect that you lock up the browser by making a SJAX request instead of an AJAX request, but that is a terrible idea.

Learn to love event driven programming when you work in an event driven programming environment.