# How to make javascript wait until it gets a valid response from synchronous http request?

Tags: javascript, wait, synchronous

I know it is not a good idea to use synchronous requests but this is the case that I really need it.

I have tried to make `getEndDate` function calling to itself if response lenght is less than 20 but after the first unsuccessfull request (if url gives too short response) it goes to `alert(enddate.EDDAYOW);` and I am getting error, and `getEndDate` continues sending request every 500 ms.

I need `getEndDate` function to continue sending a request until it get a valid response and return valid object, and only after that continue to the next line of JS. How to achieve that?

```
var url = 'http://local.com/cgi-bin/hello2.pl';
// url returns a plain text:
// 1234567890 2013 05 May Friday 13 23 45 01


var enddate = getEndDate(url);

alert(enddate.EDDAYOW);

function getEndDate(url) {
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.responseText.length > 20) {
        var n = xmlhttp.responseText.split(" ");
        return {
            'edseconds': n[0],
            'EDYEAR': n[1],
            'EDMON': n[2],
            'EDMONNAME': n[3],
            'EDDAYOW': n[4],
            'EDDAY': n[5],
            'EDHOUR': n[6],
            'EDMIN': n[7],
            'EDSEC': n[8]
        };
    } else {
        setTimeout("getEndDate(" + url + ")", 500);
    }
}


function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlhttp;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need synchronous requests in the first place?

Comment: @Blender because it should load info from other website using PHP proxy BEFORE printing page to browser.

Comment: So why aren't you doing this in PHP?

Comment: I agree with Blender, why ? my concern is that if you make this procedure a locking procedure, you will hang the browsers thread. In chrome this is (not ok) but acceptable as you'll only effect the tab running your code, but on other browsers, you may get a problem. Also have you considered the other side, what happens if your callback service is down? you will get an infinite loop, never a good thing.

Comment: The answer here might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624456/javascript-wait-for-function-response

Comment: @RussC I know about all the cons but I still need it. As for the infinite loop - I will limit it to 3 requests.

Comment: Ok, but it really would help for you to explain the Why part, please :3

Comment: @RussC It is hard to explain with my poor english skills. In a few words - it is a client-side part of a Perl script. It should load into browser, check for cookies, send required info back to Perl script, get response from that Perl script and only after that load that webpage. Without this data exchange there is no sense to show a webpage. (well, i did my best :) with my english)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this satisfies your requirement, but I would rewrite it to something like this:

```
var enddate;

getEndDate(url);

function do_rest(returnDate)
{
    enddate = returnDate;
    alert(enddate.EDDAYOW);

    // do more if you need
};


function getEndDate(url) {
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.responseText.length > 20) {
                var n = xmlhttp.responseText.split(" ");
                do_rest({
                    'edseconds': n[0],
                    'EDYEAR': n[1],
                    'EDMON': n[2],
                    'EDMONNAME': n[3],
                    'EDDAYOW': n[4],
                    'EDDAY': n[5],
                    'EDHOUR': n[6],
                    'EDMIN': n[7],
                    'EDSEC': n[8]
                });
            } else {
                setTimeout("getEndDate(" + url + ")", 500);
            }
        }
    }


    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: It is still failing when url gives response shorter than 20 chars :( And I need it to keep sending requests until it gets a valid response.

Comment: @nixoid sorry I didn't look at your code carefully. I think you need to set an event handler on `readystatechange` and handle the response in there. I don't think you can status or anything right after you do `xmlhttp.send()`. I modified my answer