# Download all ajax-loaded images from page

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, download

I'm quite a newbie to javascript, and was trying to download all images from a webpage.
these images are made available when a link is clicked, but i don't want to click all links to download all images..

I tried Firefox extension DownthEmAll, but the problem is that the several images are loaded via ajax, with non sequential urls...

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624456/javascript-wait-for-function-response), I opened firefox console and ran :

```
function downme(){
//document.getElementById("ViewerControl1_HyperLinkDownload").click();
alert("test");
}
function getlink(callback,i){
 var str1="ViewerControl1_TreeViewFilesn"+i;
 document.getElementById(str1).click();
}
//for (i==1;i<10;i++){
getlink(downme,13);
//}
```

It seems that there is a problem with the downme execution, since I am getting a 404 Not Found error when i execute it (even only with the alert). Why might this be happening?

Do you know of any way to download all images easily with having to go one by one?

Comment: save page as, webpage complete, browse to folder named the same as the file, your images should be there.

Comment: Nop, that would be too easy :-). It only downloads current loaded image